# How to catch my bluetooth service events

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, bluetooth, system-programming

I have usb bluetooth device which is using btusb 0.6 module (driver). The thing is I am interested to know is: how is the `systemctl start bluetooth.service` event invoked?

I was looking info about some kind of so called "bluetooth.service official programming interface" or similar which should help to get the `bluetooth.service` standard events info or at least to find out does the interface exist at all? But maybe there is another way?

So my question is... how to catch `bluetooth.service start/stop` etc common events or is it really possible to catch them?